# AWS - Issues with Codebuild failure

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to deploy a Flask app using AWS for my online course. So I'm currently trying to run AWS codebuild however my build keeps failing at the POST BUILD phase after trying to run the `kubectl apply -f simple_jwt_api.yml` command in my buildspec.yml file. The error I get is:

> ```
> Error: you must be logged into the server ( the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
> ```

[image]

This is the code in my buildspec.yml file:
[image]

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited:

Issue got solved after following instructions on https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-api-server-unauthorized-error/

Comment: Thanks for your response. Where would I check that? Sorry if this is a dumb question my course pretty much spoon feeds us and doesn't go into depth on how to use AWS , so when the insturctions they give us don't work we're stranded.

Comment: What is the $EKS_KUBECTL_ROLE_ARN used in codebuild?
Find out where the role is created, should be in a .yml or .json file and change the name of the role like specified above.

Comment: Okay I checked and the path of the ARN looks like the second example you provided. So : arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/another-codebuild-role. Should I still create another role?

Comment: okay, can you try out this? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-api-server-unauthorized-error/

Comment: hI Lucasz, that fixed the issue! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I've edited the answer to the one that resolved your issue. Feel free to accept.